# What does destroying the vendors do?

Tags: bioshock

There are various vendors located around Rapture. I know that destroying the health stations will yield a few first aid kits, and I overheard over the PA system an announcement warning against vandalizing the vendors. I assume that means they must drop something when they're destroyed, though I never got the opportunity to wretch one.

So what exactly do vendors drop when they're destroyed, and will it have any other effects, like cause a security alert?

Comment: You can destroy them?!

Comment: I had always assumed the comments about vandalizing the vendors referred to hacking them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is impossible to destroy the vendors. However, in Fort Frolic damaging the sculptures does cause a security alert. (not the plaster sculptures but the big plant ones)

Comment: But health machines can be destroyed: http://i.imgur.com/41fyKky.png